# How to spyOn a method of injected service?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following `JavaScript` function (note this is *not* using `Angular`) that takes in a service and uses it within to make calls:

```
function MyFunction(service) {
   var my = {};

   my.getData = function () {
      var data = service.getDataFromHttpService();
      //some other processing...
      return data;
   }

   return my;
};
```

The service looks like the following:

```
var TheDataService = (function() {
   var my = {};

   my.getDataFromHttpService = function () {
        //Call some HTTP service and get data to return...
        return data; 
   }
   return my;

}());
```

The calling code would be like the following:

```
var mf = new MyFuntion(TheDataService);
var result = mf.getData();
```

I'm trying to create a simple unit test in `jasmine` to spy in the service passed into `MyFunction` and see if `getDataFromHttpService()` has been called.

```
it("should call spyOn TheDataService and ensure getDataFromHttpService is called", function() {

      var spySrv = spyOn(TheDataService, "getDataFromHttpService");
      var mf = new MyFuntion(spySrv);

      var result = mf.getData();

      expect(TheDataService.getDataFromHttpService).toHaveBeenCalled();

   });
```

The error I get is as follows:

> TypeError: service.getDataFromHttpService is not a function

I've tried a few variations and nothing works. The actual code works outside of unit testing. The data is pulled by the service and everything is fine. Also if I test and spy directly on `TheDataService` directly and not via `MyFunction` the tests pass as well. However I need to test the service that is passed into the constructor and determine if it has been called via a spy. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using a library that creates spies for you or are you looking to do that yourself?

Comment: @sheeldotme - Yes I'm using `jasmine spies`